# Microsoft Powerpoint - GUI vs. VBA - Why Different Constraints

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Has anyone else noticed that there appear to be differences of constraints, in at least one case, when doing some operation in the GUI and doing the equivalent operation in VBA?

The example that I have noticed relates to adding a new Named Slideshow, with the Add method. If you do this in VBA, there appears to be a 31 character limit in the length of the name you give for the Slideshow:

**...NamedShows.Add Name_of_Show, Array_of Slide_IDs_in_Show**

whereas, if you do it in the GUI:

**Custom_Slide_Shows-->Custom Shows ...**

and then:

**New...**

you appear to be able to give a longer **Slide Show Name**.

I was at least expecting consistency between the two approaches (VBA and GUI).

I tried, in VBA,

1. first adding the new Slide Show with a shorter name
2. then updating the name to the intended value subsequently.
   This did not work, since, once the Show is created, the Name is a read-only property.
   I currently don't have any other ideas (apart, of course, from using a shorter name)!

```
Function SlideIndex_to_SlideID(DestPresentation As Presentation, SlideIndex As Integer) As Integer
    SlideIndex_to_SlideID = DestPresentation.Slides(SlideIndex).SlideID
End Function
Sub Try_Add_Named_Show_with_Len_Name(Len_Name As Integer)
    Dim SlideIndex As Integer
    Dim SlideIDs(1) As Integer
    Dim DestPresentation As Presentation
    Dim SlideShowName As Variant

    'Locate demo presentation
    
    Set DestPresentation = Application.Presentations("NamedSlideShows_Add_Problem_Demo")
    
    'Find ID of first slide in presentation

    SlideIndex = 1
    SlideIDs(0) = SlideIndex_to_SlideID(DestPresentation, SlideIndex)

    ' Gnenerate Name with given length for slide show

    SlideShowName = Left("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", Len_Name)

    ' Try to add the named show with that name to the presentation

    DestPresentation.SlideShowSettings.NamedSlideShows.Add SlideShowName, SlideIDs
    
End Sub
Sub Test31()
    Call Try_Add_Named_Show_with_Len_Name(31)
End Sub
Sub Test32()
    Call Try_Add_Named_Show_with_Len_Name(32)
End Sub
```

Testcase **Test31** runs without error but, with **Test32**, you get an error reported:

[image]

complaining that names longer than 31 characters are not allowed.

However, if, after running **Test31**, you go to the **SLIDE SHOW** GUI in thr ribbon, choose **Custom Shows...** from the drop down and **Edit** the 31 character named slide show from the **Custom Shows** list box then you appear still to be able to add extra characters to the end of the name, without objection:

[image]

Hitting **OK**, closing the **Custom Shows** list box and saving and exiting the presentation still seems to leave the extended **Slide Show Name** in place, when the presentation is re-opened.

It is this apparent inconsistent treatment of the longer SlideShowName (between the GUI and VBA) whch forms the substance of this report.

Comment: There's no VBA command called NmedSHows, nor one called Shows or Show. Perhaps you could post your code. The VBA object model has only the commands that Microsoft programs into it, which in recent years has been fewer and fewer of the commands found in the program interface.

Comment: New information has been added to initial posting, as you requested. I hope that this will allow you to make a more detailed analysis of my report.

Comment: If you define a Custom Show with a long name in the GUI, what does VBA tell you the .Name is? Is it truncated, suggesting that there is some other property holding the name shown in the GUI?

Comment: To report a bug to Microsoft, choose File>Feedback>Send a Frown in PowerPoint. If you create a sample slide with your illustrations, you can include a screen shot when you submit the report. Microsoft is unlikely to reply.

Comment: Andrew, the answer is that VBA comes up with the extended name, just as the GUI does, after you quit the PowerPoint session and re-open the presentation.